# Security Question: Distribution of services over virtual machines

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization

I am about to setup my new dedicated server with a couple of services. Previously I installed them directly "bare-metal" on the same server. Now I want to use virtual machines to secure it.

***What approach is better and why?***

**VM 1:** mysql

**VM 2:** nginx (nextcloud, wordpress, reverse proxy, ...)

**VM 3:** gitlab

*OR*

**HOST:** nginx (reverse proxy)

**VM 1:** nginx, nextcloud, mysql

**VM 2:** nginx, wordpress, mysql

**VM 3:** gitlab

*OR*

(your proposal)

I think, the second is better, because each service has everything it needs. But I could also think of the first one if for example the database vm is like fort knox (but if someone has hacked nextcloud, he has also access to nextcloud database in database vm....so I dont know)

Comment: [Stack Overflow Developer Survey Ranks WordPress as the 3rd Most Dreaded Technology](https://wptavern.com/stack-overflow-developer-survey-ranks-wordpress-as-the-3rd-most-dreaded-technology)

Comment: What has this to do with my question?